# XSS in forgot password

Tags: security, magento, xss

Using the POST HTTP method, Site Scanner found that :

- The following resources may be vulnerable to cross-site scripting (extended patterns) :
- The 'email' parameter of the /customer/account/forgotpasswordpost/ CGI :
  /customer/account/forgotpasswordpost/ [email=508 src=http://www.example.
  com/exploit508.js]

As far I see code, Magento senitize the _GET/_POST. How can I get fixed this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this will depend on what version of Magento you are running. The default location for the template in question can be found at `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml`. The only value that is user editable that is echo'd out to the screen is the e-mail address, certainly in Magento 1.6 this is being passed through the template blocks htmlEscape method, but it's worth checking that it is in your version of Magento.

```
<input type="text" name="email" alt="email" id="email_address" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getEmailValue()) ?>" />
```

If you find that it already is then it would be worth checking that this template isn't being overloaded in your current theme.